# CarPark is not an abstract and does not override abstract method (need help)

Tags: java, swing, abstract

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * This programs counts the cars entering and leaving a car park, always displaying
 * the current number of cars in the car park.
 */
public class CarPark extends JFrame
implements ActionListener{

/**
 * Globally accessible counter for the number of cars in the car park
 */
private int carCount = 0;

/**
 * Globally accessible counter for the number of mini buses in the car park
 */
private int miniCount = 0;

/**
 * Globally accessible counter for the total amount of spaces left
 */
private int limitCalc = 100;

/**
 * Buttons to simulate cars entering and leaving the car park.
 */
private JButton enter, exit, miniEnter, miniExit;

/**
 * Text field where the current number of cars is displayed
 */
private JTextField text, miniText, carMax;

/**
 * The main launch method
 */

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    CarPark frame = new CarPark();
    frame.setSize(400, 250);
    frame.setLocation(150, 150);
    frame.setTitle("Car Park");
    frame.createGUI();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

/**
 * React to a GUI button press by adjusting the car counter correctly,
 * and then updating the counter display
 */
/**
 * Helper method to build up the GUI
 */
private void createGUI()
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container window = getContentPane();
    window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    int carLimit = 100;

    enter = new JButton("Car Entering");
    window.add(enter);
    enter.addActionListener(this);

    text = new JTextField("0   ");
    text.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));
    window.add(text);

    exit = new JButton("Car Exiting");
    window.add(exit);
    exit.addActionListener(this);

    miniEnter = new JButton("Minibus Entering");
    window.add(miniEnter);
    miniEnter.addActionListener(this);

    miniText = new JTextField("0   ");
    miniText.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));
    window.add(miniText);

    miniExit = new JButton("Minibus Exiting");
    window.add(miniExit);
    miniExit.addActionListener(this);

    carMax = new JTextField(carLimit + "");
    carMax.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));
    window.add(carMax);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event, int carLimit)
{
    if (event.getSource() == enter)
    {
        carCount = carCount + 1;
        limitCalc = limitCalc-1;
        System.out.println(limitCalc);
    }
    if (event.getSource() == exit)
    {
        carCount = carCount-1;
        limitCalc = limitCalc +1;
        System.out.println(limitCalc);
    }
    if (event.getSource() == miniEnter)
    {
        miniCount = miniCount+1;
        limitCalc = limitCalc -1;
        System.out.println(limitCalc);
    }
    if (event.getSource() == miniExit)
    {
        miniCount = miniCount-1;
        limitCalc = limitCalc +1;
        System.out.println(limitCalc);
    }

    miniText.setText(Integer.toString(miniCount));
    text.setText(Integer.toString(carCount));

}

private int carCalculations(int carLimit)
{
    int carTotal = carCount + miniCount;
    limitCalc = limitCalc - carTotal;
    carLimit = limitCalc;
    System.out.println(carLimit);
    return carLimit;
}
}
```

I keep getting this error

```
"CarPark is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in java.awt.event.ActionListener
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" Not implementing `actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent)`.

Comment: This program is being used for 4 buttons, 3 text boxes, 2 of those text boxes are holding the values, miniCount & carCount, the third text box is used to calculate how many spaces are left out of 100

Comment: @Smutje where would I put this line of code?

Comment: Where you put your "overridden" `actionPerformed` method. Learn about interfaces.

Comment: @Smutje I'm new to java, would I put this inside of the method or outside?

Comment: *Please* do yourself a favor and read about interfaces and inheritance before playing with AWT and similar stuff.

Comment: @Smutje Already told this to my lecturer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of overriding the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` method you are overloading it with `actionPerformed(ActionEvent, int)`.

Think about the way you can remove the `int` part from  your method signature.